# How can I echo it when a user logs in and when a user logs out?

Tags: php

So basically I'm doing my Login system and I came across an error.

```
<?php
 require "header.php";
?>

     <main>
       <div class="wrapper-main">
         <section class="section-default">
           <?php
           if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
             echo '<p class = "login-status">You are logged in!</p>';
           }
           else {
              echo '<p class = "login-status">You are logged out!</p>';
           }
            ?>
         </section>
       </div>
     </main>

     <?php
       require "footer.php";
     ?>
```

```
$_SESSION['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
$_SESSION['userUid'] = $row['uidUsers'];
```

When I press the login button it doesn't echo "You are logged in!". Instead, it keeps echoing "You are logged out!"

Comment: Missing `session_start();`?

Comment: I already applied "session_start()" in my header.php

Comment: Did you forget to include your header.php

Comment: Yes, I added <?php
 require "header.php";
?>

Comment: I updated my post, see if it helps

Comment: Share the code where you set a value for $_SESSION['userId']

Comment: Done! See if this helps you :)

Comment: Is the `session_start()` in your header file run before any bytes of output are sent?

Comment: `<?php session_start(); ?>` Needs to be the very first line. Nothing else must come before it.

Comment: My <?php session_start(); ?> is before anything in my header.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 session_start();
 require "header.php";
...
```

Comment: You should add an explanation to your answer. If you post code without explanation the OP or someone else (who might find this question in future) might not understand what was the cause of the problem. Then they might not be able to use your answer when the code is slightly different but problem is same.